# What is the following interpretation of Conditional Expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I am talking about the Measure Theoretic definition of Conditional Expectation. We say that for two random variables $X$ and $Y$, the conditional expectation $E(X|Y)$ is a $\sigma(Y)$-measurable function of $Y$ such that, for all $A\in\sigma(Y)$ we have,$$E[E(X|Y)1_A]=E(X1_A)$$.

Then, how does one "define" things like $E(X|Y\in B)$ where $B\in\sigma(Y)$? Does it mean that $$E[E(X|Y)1_A]=E(X1_A)$$ for every $A\in B\cap\sigma(Y)$?

In that case, how does one define conditional probabilities like $P(X\in T|Y\in B)$? For simplicity, we can assume $Y$ to be a discrete and absolutely continuous r.v. only.

Comment: It "should" be $E (X|A)=E (X1_A)/P (A)$. In the discrete case this works as is. Translate it for the general case.

Comment: Is what you wrote the definition?

Comment: Not in general, because $P (A)$ could be zero. But it is the intuition behind the definition in general.

Comment: Actually, I am a bit confused about these. It would be really helpful if you could suggest any book/pdf where these are clearly written, all the definitions, what we are alloed to use, what we cannot use, etc. Thanks!

Comment: *Probability with martingales*, David Williams.

Comment: Hello Did! I recently went through quite a large no. of books but none seems to explain the meaning of $E(X|Y\in B)$. So, please tell me, is the thing I've written in the question right?

Comment: More precisely, you can introduce $E (X|1_A) $. This is a function on $\Omega $ which is entirely determined by whether $\omega \in A $. For $\omega \in A $, we call the value of this function at $\omega$ $ E (X|A) $.

Comment: I am sorry if I am appearing dumb, and irritating you, but again, is this a definition? Anyway, I find this development really helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: Once you can define $E (X|1_A) $, what I wrote is a definition of $E (X|A) $.

Comment: Perfect. I know the definition of the former, and you have just given a new name to it.

Comment: Note that this definition is actually not very helpful for actually calculating anything except in the discrete case. For instance, suppose $X,Y$ are iid uniform on $[0,1]$ and you want to calculate $E[|X|^3 + |Y|^3 \mid X^2+Y^2=1]$. (This is a reasonable question; you can intuitively see that the answer is about 1, but a bit less.) For this continuous situation it is more convenient to have a different definition in terms of delta functions: $E[|X|^3 + |Y|^3 \mid X^2+Y^2=1]=\frac{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (|x|^3+|y|^3) \delta(x^2+y^2-1) dx dy}{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \delta(x^2+y^2-1) dx dy}$.

Comment: One can then actually calculate this using the "co-area formula" (which in this simple case amounts to saying "use polar coordinates").

Comment: Well, thank you again! However, my current concern is to relate the "theoretical" definition of conditional expectation to the more common computational ones (for discrete and absolutely continuous case). My aim is to show that these theoretical definitions match our pre-existing notions. For the time being I cannot really use your "formula" because I have not yet shown that it is precisely the theoretical concept.

Comment: One question though: I know the definition of $E(X|1_A)$. But how do I find out the definition of $E(X|1_A=1)$? We are back to the same problem: finding $E(X|B)$ where $B$ is an event.

Comment: It is $E(X|1_A)(\omega)$, for any $\omega \in A$. A helpful fact for generalizing this: because $E(X|Y)$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, there exists a Borel measurable function $\phi$ such that $E(X|Y)(\omega)=\phi(Y(\omega))$.

Comment: A final thank you. I believe you have helped me a lot this afternoon.